# Why in a Java switch over an Integer wrapper, does a 'char' case not compile, but compilation is OK when the switch is over Byte?

Tags: java, java-8, switch-statement

Does not compile:

```
void test(Integer x) {
      switch (x) {
          case 'a':
      }
}
```

---

Compiles OK:

```
void test(Byte x) {
      switch(x) {
          case 'a':
      }
}
```

Comment: Integer is 4 bytes while char is 2 bytes. So in the first case, no matter what character you write, it is smaller than integer. In the second case however, the character that you wrote could be bigger than the maximum byte, making that case never execute.

Comment: That explanation is incorrect.  Indeed, in the 2nd example, code in the `'a'` case *will* be executed in the case that `x` is the byte `97`.  (Try it if you don't believe me.)  For the real explanation, see my answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reasons are rather complicated, but they are all in the details (*fine print* if you like) of the Java Language Specification.

First of, the [JLS 14.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) says the following about `switch` statements:

> *"Every case constant associated with the switch statement must be assignment compatible with the type of the switch statement's Expression ([§5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2))."*

This means that `'a'` needs to be assignable to `Integer` and `Byte`  respectively.

But that doesn't sound right:

- *You would think* that since `'a'` *should be* assignable to an `Integer` because `char` -> `int`  assignment is legal.  (Any `char` value will fit into an `int`.)
- *You would think* that since `'a'` *should NOT be* assignable to an `Byte` because `char` -> `byte`  assignment is NOT legal.  (Most `char` values won't fit into a byte.)

In fact, neither of these is correct.  To understand why, we need to read what [JLS 5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) actually about what is allowed in assignment contexts.

> *"Assignment contexts allow the use of **one of the following**:*
>
> - *an identity conversion (§5.1.1)*
> - *a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)*
> - *a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)*
> - *a widening reference conversion followed by an unboxing conversion*
> - *a widening reference conversion followed by an unboxing conversion, then followed by a widening primitive conversion*
> - *a boxing conversion (§5.1.7)*
> - *a boxing conversion followed by a widening reference conversion*
> - *an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8)*
> - *an unboxing conversion followed by a widening primitive conversion."*

To go from `'a'` to `Integer`, we would need to<sup>1</sup> widen the `char` value to an `int` then box the `int` to an `Integer`.  But if you look at the combinations of conversions that are allowed, you cannot do a widening primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion.

Therefore `'a'` to `Integer` is not allowed.  This explains the compilation error in the first case.

You would think that `'a'` to `Byte` is disallowed because that would involve a primitive narrowing conversion ... which is not in the list at all.  In fact, literals are a special case.  [JLS 5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) goes on to say the following.

> *"In addition, if the expression is a constant expression ([§15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)) of type byte, short, char, or int:*
>
> - *A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the variable is of type byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.*
> - *A narrowing primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion may be used if the variable is of type `Byte`, `Short`, or `Character`, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type byte, short, or char respectively."*

The second of these applies to `'a'` to `Byte`, because:

- a character literal is a constant expression, and
- the value of `'a'` is `97` decimal, which is within the range for `byte` (`-128` to `+127`).

This explains why there is no compilation error in the second example.

---

<sup>1 - We can't box `'a'` to a `Character` and then widen `Character` to `Integer` because `Character` is not a Java subtype of `Integer`.  You can only use a widening reference conversion if the source type is a subtype of the target type.</sup>

Comment: Can we use `int` as the switch type? (since `char -> int` is primitive widening which is allowed)